# Is there a way to keep my gsheet automatically sorted by date as I enter new line items of data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to keep my google sheet automatically sorted by date as I enter new line items of data?

Comment: You can use an onEdit trigger. Please post you code in the question.  Personally, I do not follow links to offsite resources

Comment: Looks like you have a sort function in your code already?  Is this not working as intended or has it since been added?

Answer (score 0):

This will sort all of your sheets on every edit:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  e.source.getSheets().forEach(sh => sh.getRange(8,1,sh.getLastRow() - 7, sh.getLastColumn()).sort({column:1,ascend:true}));
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

> You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need tp perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

> There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."

Comment: Where are you quoting this text from?